# How can I make a symbolic link to run a program with command line argument?

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link

How can I make a symbolic link to run a program with command line argument?
For example, I want to run `sample` with `-i eth0` argument every time when I click on a symbol link.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For this use case, I would recommend writing a shell script instead, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
sample -i eth0
```

Then save the script in `/usr/local/bin` as e.g. mySample, make it runnable with `chmod +x mySample`. And there you go :)