# update-alternatives path with arguments

Tags: command-line, wine

I want to add a command to notepadd++ intallation using update-alternatives with wine command:

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/notepad notepad "/<path_to_wine>/bin/wine C:\\Program\ Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe" 100`

But I get an error:

> update-alternatives: error: alternative path //bin/wine
>   C:\Program\ Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe doesn't exist

Is there a way to add program arguments to update-alternatives path parameter?

Note:  is my teamviewer wine installation: /opt/teamviewer9/tv_bin/wine/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to create a simple shell script wrapper for the command that you want to invoke, and then add the path to the shell script to the alternatives system.

For your case, you could create a shell script at `/usr/local/bin/wine-notepad++` (or whatever path and name you prefer) with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /opt/teamviewer9/tv_bin/wine/bin/wine C:\\Program\ Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe "$@"
```

You can then add the path to this script to the alternatives system using `update-alternatives` if you want, with

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/notepad notepad /usr/local/bin/wine-notepad++ 100
```

Note that alternatives in Ubuntu are implemented with symbolic links, so this is a very similar question and answer to [How can I make a symbolic link to run a program with command line argument?](https://askubuntu.com/q/323887/70254).

Comment: It works! I added it to nautilus "open with" menu using Ubuntu Tweak. Thank you